# Get the transaction id when the transaction is committed

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

I am using IEnlistmentNotification interface from transaction scope and I want to access the current transaction id in the commit method after the scope is completed like this:

```
public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
{     
    string transactionId = Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier;
    enlistment.Done();
}
```

But I am getting an error because now the transaction.current is null.
From what I check the enlistment instance has private member of the transactionId, but I can't access it for his protection level.

Is there another way to get the transaction id when the scope is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (YourContext context = new YourContext())
            {
                //DB operations
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += Current_TransactionCompleted;
            TransactionInformation info = Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation;
            string transactionId = Guid.Empty.Equals(info.DistributedIdentifier) ? info.LocalIdentifier : info.DistributedIdentifier.ToString();
            scope.Complete();
        }

        //For the transaction completed event:
        private void Current_TransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
        {
             //e.Transaction.TransactionInformation contains the Id
        }
```